# Is it possible to integrate Neil Crookes' search plugin to cakephp 2.0?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to integrate Neil's search plugin http://www.neilcrookes.com/2009/11/21/cakephp-searchable-plugin to my application but I can't get it to work. Does it work with Cakephp 2.0 and how do I go about doing it?

Thanks,
Lyman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is CakeDCs search plugin not an option? its very sophisticated and works in 2.0. 
Ah, I see. The functionality is completely different.

Well, I don't see any 2.0 implementations yet. But you can easily upgrade it using the UpgradeShell.

run "cake upgrade all -p Searchable"

Comment: How do you do this?
Run the build_search_index shell, e.g.

$> cake build_search_index

Comment: What do you mean? you first have to upgrade from 1.3 to 2.0 before you can use it!

Comment: I already ran "cake upgrade all -p Searchable". just having a hard time running the step 4 on this site http://www.neilcrookes.com/2009/11/21/cakephp-searchable-plugin

Comment: the shells also changed. it would now be "cake Searchable.build_search_index" or even better: "cake Searchable.BuildSearchIndex"

Comment: The successor for CakePHP3+ is https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search by the way

Comment: That's what I just implemented on a side project recently Mark and I posted a question about it. :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505065/how-to-pass-friendsofcake-search-results-onto-different-view-in-cakephp-3-x

Answer (score 1):

I've made the necessary changes to Jose Gonzalez's fork of Searchable in order to get it compatible with CakePHP 2.0. You can get it here - https://github.com/sc0ttyd/searchable
Remember to check out the 2.0 branch for CakePHP 2.0 compatibility.