# How to pass friendsofcake/search results onto different view in CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I've successfully implemented friendsofcake/search plugin into my app but I'm having a hard time passing the results of my search onto another page. Is this possible? If so, where would I configure it on my app?

Say, on my index.ctp where my search form is, I want the output to be on search.ctp.

Thanks!

Comment: You simply pass them along with `'?' => $this->request->query` in links.

Comment: Thanks @mark! While waiting for a response, I did a workaround on my view like so:

`<?php echo $this->Form->create('Items', array('url' => array('action' => 'index'));`

Where will I put `'?' => $this->request->query`?

Comment: besides 'action' of course, it is on the same level as any url parameter - as documented.